# the Time complexity of an algorithm

Tags: c#, algorithm

I am learning algorithms at the moment and wrote this below code, which finds if a peak exists in a one dimensional array. my question is how do I know its time complexity of its best case or average case?

The worst case time complexity (if the element of the array are sorted) is O(n), but if the array is not sorted and it has 10 elements the code runs 5 loops to get the result, which is half of the array size, so can anyone tell me how to write this in algorithmic notation.

```
 int[] arr = { 1,5,2,7,8,9,4,6,7};
 int peak;

 int count = 0;
 for (int i = 1; i < arr.Length - 1; i++)
 {
            peak = -1;
            if (arr[i - 1] <= arr[i] && arr[i] >= arr[i + 1])
            {
                peak = arr[i];
                i++;
            }
            else if (arr[i - 1] >= arr[i] && i - 1 == 0)
            {
                peak = arr[i - 1];
            }
            else if (arr[i + 1] >= arr[i] && i + 1 == arr.Length - 1)
            {
                peak = arr[i + 1];
            }

            if (peak != -1)
                listBox1.Items.Add(peak.ToString());

            count++;
}

listBox1.Items.Add(count.ToString());
```

Comment: I think O(n) is still true, even though your sorted case runs in n/2.  Big-Oh doesn't care about constants.  Not about absolute time; only relative.

Comment: You can't say that this algorithm will run 5 loops if there are 10 elements and the array is not sorted. It could be unsorted and run 7 loops, or 3 loops.

Comment: Thanks, but it is my non sorted case which runs n/2.

Comment: @MannfromReno you are right, so this means it is still o(n) as duffymo  said.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would still write it as `O(n)` because Big-O is worst case (which here is linear time.) In this case `n` is of course the array length. Theoretically nothing inside your loop exceeds `O(1)` (I'm going to ignore the list append and call it constant.)

After noticing your comments about `n/2` iterations. `n/2` is the same as saying `(1/2)n` or `O((1/2)n)` this is equivalent to `O(n)` because we ignore all coefficients when doing bounding with Big-O.

Comment: Big-O is not worst case, it is amortized cost. If it where worst case HashSet and Dictionary lookups would be considered `O(n)` not `O(1)`

Comment: @ScottChamberlain There's no worse than `O(1)` lookups in his example.  The only thing to worry about would be the list append which, and it's not clear what that list type is, is at worst `O(n)` so if we wanted to really get technical we could argue the runtime is actually `O(n^2)` or possibly `O(nlogn)` but in most cases like this we'll call everything inside that loop `O(1)` for simplicity.

Comment: `k.ToString()` is O(log k) since it creates a string with O(log k) digits. So assuming the array contains numbers of a similar size to the size of the array, the code is O(n log n) in the worst case if not sorted.